# Is it possible to export Wikipedia Templates using Special:Export in 2017?

Tags: xml, templates, export, wikipedia

I have an issue when I trying to export Wikipedia Templates (eg: WikipediaURL/Template:Multiple_image OR WikipediaURL/Template:MI  ) using Special:Export to my own wiki.

Special:Export Process Picture:

[image: image1]

Output File XML Picture:

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

Try without the full url

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn9rd.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGD77.jpg)